# How to disable the calculations log of pulp

Tags: python, gurobi, pulp

I am using "pulp" in python together with GUROBI to solve some optimization problems. For example, the calculations log for GUROBI is:

```
Optimize a model with 12 rows, 25 columns and 39 nonzeros
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range    [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Objective range [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Bounds range    [1e+00, 1e+00]
  RHS range       [1e+00, 1e+00]
Found heuristic solution: objective 12
Presolve removed 3 rows and 12 columns
Presolve time: 0.00s
Presolved: 9 rows, 13 columns, 27 nonzeros
Variable types: 0 continuous, 13 integer (13 binary)

Root relaxation: objective 7.000000e+00, 11 iterations, 0.00 seconds

    Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

*    0     0               0       7.0000000    7.00000  0.00%     -    0s

Explored 0 nodes (11 simplex iterations) in 0.00 seconds
Thread count was 4 (of 4 available processors)

Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective 7.000000000000e+00, best bound 7.000000000000e+00, gap 0.0%
('Gurobi status=', 2)
```

I want to disable this output because I am going to solve 800k optimization problems and writing these logs in the output make my code too slow. Any idea for disabling these logs?

Answer (score 9):

You need to explicitly declare a solver so replace this line

```
p.solve()
```

with this

```
p.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=0))
```

or replace `PULP_CBC_CMD with whatever solver you are using.

Answer (score 5):

I just found how we can do that:
instead of default way of calling Gurobi which is:

```
pulp.GUROBI().solve(prob)
```

we need to write:

```
pulp.GUROBI(msg=0).solve(prob)
```

Answer (score 3):

m0_as's answer is correct. Just want to share some more details. In PuLP library each solver class derives from the same base class LpSolver.

```
class LpSolver:
    """A generic LP Solver"""

    def __init__(self, mip = True, msg = True, options = [], *args, **kwargs):
        self.mip = mip
        self.msg = msg
        self.options = options
```

In the constructor these is msg parameter which defines if you want to echo information from solver to stdout. This is implementation of [class GUROBI](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/master/src/pulp/solvers.py#L1774)

See line 1774 it says

```
    @param msg: displays information from the solver to stdout
```

You can easily found other solver specific parameters in this source file very easily.