# How to disable the generating gurobi.log file when using PuLP and Gurobi as solver?

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, gurobi, pulp

I am using PuLP and Gurobi to solve thousands of MILP problem. **I don't want to generate gurobi.log** file and delete it every time because that is time-consuming. And I found an question here
[How to disable the calculations log of pulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237449/how-to-disable-the-calculations-log-of-pulp). This helps to stop printing log in the console. But I want to stop generating log files. Could anyone help me please? Thank you!

Comment: @m0_as sorry to bother, but I see your answer in another related question and I think maybe you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: That's not how @-mentions work here. You can't ping someone unless they have already commented on, asked, or answered a question.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), as well as [ask]. Please also follow the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer. In fact, you can pass any Gurobi parameter using PuLP as an interface. So I checked Gurobi's official document [stop gurobi.log](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/outputflag.html#parameter:OutputFlag).
So, `model.solve(GUROBI_CMD(logPath = '', options = [('LogToConsole', 0)]))` or `model.solve(GUROBI_CMD(options = [('OutputFlag', 0)]))` will work.